Spring boot 3 azureAD userinfo
I want to customize Oauth2USer with a service after the authentification.
I made this config
_http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .cors(CorsConfigurer::disable)
        .headers(headers -> headers.cacheControl(CacheControlConfig::disable))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**", "/webjars/**", "/",
            "/index", "/login", "/loginfailed", "/logout", "/version", "/simulation", "/simulation.*").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/index", true).failureUrl("/loginfailed"))
        .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
            .loginPage("/login")
            .userInfoEndpoint(userInfoEndpoint -> userInfoEndpoint
                .userService(customAzureAdUserService))
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/test", true));

However this customAzureAdUserService is not getting called despite the authentification being ok.
Here the customAzureAdUAserService which i want to call in order to complete this information from application. I think that it good matter to do.
@Service
public class CustomAzureAdUserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(final OAuth2UserRequest userRequest)
        throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2User oAuth2User = super.loadUser(userRequest);
 
        Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>(oAuth2User.getAttributes());
        Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>(oAuth2User.getAuthorities());
      
        // Custom Dev

        return new DefaultOAuth2User(mappedAuthorities, attributes, "name"); 
  }
}


please show customAzureAdUserService implementation and explain what do you want it exactly to do?

I put the code in the initail Message. I want complete the user with custom information from the application

I create a bean which must to be called after the authentification

i don't publish all the code. But i think it is enought to undersant my problem

i think the problem comes from spring. I have the feedback from Azure but I don't have the correct feedback in the OIDC chain. the service I customize is not called. that the problem

Do you use oidcservice for my case?

What keys are mandatory in the application.properties file?
